# Changing password for multiple excel files in a folder

Tags: excel, vba

I have multiple files in a folder and each of them have different password (which I have with me). Every week, I need to open the file using the password and save it without password (for an automation to pick the files).
I am using the below code which does the job. But it's slow and takes a few mins even if it's less than 10 files. Anything wrong with the code?

Please help!

```
Sub blah()
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
mFolder = "folder path"
Set mainfolder = objFSO.GetFolder(mFolder)
Dim xValue As String
Dim OutValue As String
Dim PW As String
For Each fil In mainfolder.Files
  PW = ""
  xValue = ""
  OutValue = ""
  xValue = fil.Name
  For xIndex = 1 To VBA.Len(xValue)
      If Not VBA.IsNumeric(VBA.Mid(xValue, xIndex, 1)) Then
          OutValue = OutValue & VBA.Mid(xValue, xIndex, 1)
      End If
  Next
  TextOnly = Split(OutValue, ".")
  If LCase(Left(TextOnly(UBound(TextOnly)), 4)) = "xlsx" Then
      PW = Replace(OutValue, ".xlsx", "taxipw")
  ElseIf LCase(Left(TextOnly(UBound(TextOnly)), 3)) = "xls" Then
      PW = Replace(OutValue, ".xls", "taxipw")
  End If
  Set myWB = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=fil, Password:=PW)
  myWB.Password = ""
  myWB.Close True
Next fil
End Sub
```

Comment: Perhaps each file could open itself and unset/set the password using application.ontime? (It will probably not make it faster but it won't require your maintenance)

Comment: @Andreas Not sure how I do that. Please advise

Comment: Actually I see nothing really wrong with that code. Depending on the filesize and if it is on the network opening a file and saving it will take some amount of time. Further the amount of files is making a difference. So maybe it can improve a bit to put the files on a highspeed SSD instead of a slow network but that's probably not what you want. • To make it less an issue for you (so you don't have to wait for it) what about automation of the process. Put a similar code as VBScript and launch it with Task Scheduler at a specific date/time so it runs automatically in the background.